# jquery fadeout current div, find next div and fade in or find last and fade in

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I have div class called .stage which is a stage of a questionnaire

```
<div class="stage">
    <div class="next">Next</div>
</div>
<div class="stage">
    <div class="back">Back</div>
    <div class="next">Next</div>
</div>
<div class="stage">
    <div class="back">Back</div>
    <div class="next">Next</div>
</div>
<div class="stage">
    <div class="back">Back</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to write some compact jQuery that if you select next it closes the current stage and opens the next stage or if you click back it closes current stage opens last one and so on..

```
$(".next").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".stage").fadeOut();
        (".stage").next().fadeIn();
    });
$(".back").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".stage").fadeOut();
        (".stage").last().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Not having much luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need some chaining changes, like this:

```
$(".next").click(function () {
  $(this).closest(".stage").fadeOut().next().fadeIn();
});
$(".back").click(function () {
  $(this).closest(".stage").fadeOut().prev().fadeIn();
});
```

Note the use of [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) for the previous sibling, rather than [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) which gets the last element in the set.  If you don't want the cross-fade, do the fade-in inside the callback, like this:

```
$(".next").click(function () {
  $(this).closest(".stage").stop().fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeIn();
  });
});
$(".back").click(function () {
  $(this).closest(".stage").stop().fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).prev().fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: perfect thanks.

Yeah at first when I was selecting back it was reloading the current stage (saw it as the last)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var i = 0;
var $stages = $('.stage');
$('.next').click(function() {
  $($stages[i]).fadeOut();
  i++;
  $($stages[i]).fadeIn();
});
$('.back').click(function() {
  $($stages[i]).fadeOut();
  i--;
  $($stages[i]).fadeIn();
});
```

By doing it this way and tracking which item the user's on, you can also always retrieve the current stage that should be visible by doing `$stages[i]`.

Comment: I got an error with this

$stages[i].fadeOut is not a function ?

Thanks for quick reponse

Comment: Whoops, my bad - I don't have access to something to test it on, you'd need to wrap $stages[i] inside $(). I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AJFMEDIA, @Like - If you click quickly...this won't function correctly, better to find it relatively at the time of the click.

Comment: Right, good point; Nick's solution is better if you're worried about someone clicking quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="stage">  
<h1>stage 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="stage">   
<h1>stage 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="stage">   
<h1>stage 3</h1>
</div>
<div class="stage">
<h1>stage 4</h1>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

             var navBtns = "BackNext";
            $(".stage").hide().append(navBtns);
            $(".stage:first .fade_back").hide();
            $(".stage:last .fade_next").hide();
            $(".stage:first").show();

            $(".fade_next").click(function() {
                $(this).closest(".stage").hide();
                $(this).closest(".stage").next(".stage").fadeIn("slow");
            });

            $(".fade_back").click(function() {
                $(this).closest(".stage").hide();
                $(this).closest(".stage").prev(".stage").fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });





.fade_nav{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;   
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.fade_back, .fade_next{
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.fade_back:hover, .fade_next:hover{
    background-color: #000;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little slow on the draw. Mostly the same idea aas the above. However, the 'next' and 'back' button markup is a bit repetitive and could be added dynamically. Here is a jsfiddle showing how to add:

http://jsfiddle.net/tBwYA/

Hope you find this useful.

Bob